# What's the difference between prepositional phrase and adverbial complement?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> “I try to give ‘em a reason, you see. It helps folks if they can
>   **latch onto a reason**.”
>  (Harper Lee, To Kill A Mockingbird)

When we say ‘prepositional verb’ and ‘adverbial complement,’ are they two points of view for one occasion: the former sees ‘latch onto a reason’ as [prepositional verb: latch onto]+[a reason], and the other [latch]+[adverbial complement: onto a reason].’ Or does the example show only the prepositional verb?

Comment: The situation may or may not be complicated by confecting the preposition *onto* which should be two words. *Into* is a preposition; *onto* is not.

Comment: ..........Pardon?  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onto

Comment: Like _into_ or _without_, _onto_ is a compound preposition.

Comment: The usage note at _Collins_ is relevant: < **Usage**: _Onto_ is now generally accepted as a word in its own right. _On to_ is still used, however, where _on_ is considered to be part of the verb: _he moved on to a different town_ as contrasted with _he jumped onto the stage_.> _Latch on to_ and _latch onto_ are both acceptable, perhaps showing an intermediate degree of cohesiveness between _latch_ and _on_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A prepositional phrase is a grammatical structure consisting of a preposition followed by a noun phrase. An adverbial complement is a grammatical function. Adverbial complements may be realized through prepositional phrases or other adverbials.

Consider:

*I put the book **down**.*

*I put the book **on the table**.*

*I put the book **down on the table**.*

There are verbs requiring complements without which the sentence they are part of would be malformed. In your example, the verb **latch** is such a verb. The addition of the adverbial particle *onto* in conjuction with the verb *latch* gives it an entirely different meaning than if *latch* were used in a sentence such as *Make sure to latch the gate.*

Therefore, I would argue that the verbal structure in your example is *latch onto* and that this structure is followed by the noun phrase *a reason*. In terms of function, I would say that *latch onto* is a verb and *a reason* is a direct object.

Comment: Yes, I agree that _latch on to_ is an example of the good old multi-word verb. I can't think of a one-word synonym, but _see_ , _apprehend_, _grasp_ or _have_ (here) are reasonably close. But I'd stick with _latch on to_. _Latch onto_ is a permitted variant ( http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/latch+onto and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/latch ). _Onto_ is prepositional not adverbial, whether used as a preposition or particle.

Comment: There's also _grab/get/take (a)hold of_.